# How to wrap ggplot subtitle when using expression function to create the text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am create a ggplot2 with long subtitle text. I need to wrap the text to multiple lines. I am using `expression()` to add italics, subscripts, etc. to the subtitle, and cannot figure out how to wrap when using this function.

MWE:

```r
ggplot() +
  labs(title = "Figure 3",
       subtitle = expression("This is a really long title"["with subscripts"]~"in expression() using ggplot that I would like to wrap to multiple lines but I cannot figure out how to do this when using expression() to create the subtitle"))
```

[image]

Comment: Try using \n where you want the breaks to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `atop()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  labs(
    title = "Figure 3",
    subtitle = expression(atop(
      "This is a really long title"["with subscripts"]~"in expression() using ggplot that I would like to wrap to", 
      "multiple lines but I cannot figure out how to do this when using expression() to create the subtitle"
    ))
  )
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`ggtext::element_textbox_simple()`](https://wilkelab.org/ggtext/reference/element_textbox.html) to style your text with HTML/CSS tags. This has the added bonus of wrapping your text automatically, without you having to figure out where to place the break(s).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot() +
  labs(
    title = "Figure 3",
    subtitle = "This is a really long title<sub>with subscripts</sub> and <b><i style='color:red;'>red bold italics</b></i> using ggtext that I would like to wrap to multiple lines but I cannot figure out how to do this when using expression() to create the subtitle"
  ) +
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_textbox_simple())
```

[image]